# Object.keys forEach loop reads the whole object

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I have an object filled with arrays called 'player' containing 5 names each. I want to loop and stop once all 5 have been read, but this code reads the whole object instead of just 5.

```
$(function () {
    var $playerSubMenu = $("li.teams ul.sub_menu li");
    var $playerAdd = "";
    $playerAdd += "<ul>";
    Object.keys(team).sort().forEach(function (a) {
        for (var i = 0; i < team[a].player.length; i++) {
            var $players = "<li><a href=\"#\">" + team[a].player[i] + "</a></li>";
            $playerAdd += $players;
        }
    });
    $playerAdd += "</ul>";
    $($playerSubMenu).append($playerAdd);
});
```

Here is a snippet of the 'team' object that this jQuery is pulling from:

```
c9: {id: "8", team: "Cloud9", player: ["n0thing", "seang@res", "shroud", "Skadoodle", "freakazoid"], country: "USA"},
```

[Here is a picture illustrating what is going wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Knusf.jpg).

My plan is to add a list item for each player, but what ends up happening is I get 100 list items (every 'player' in the 'team' object). I have tried:

```
Object.keys(team).sort().every(function (a) {
    same code as above...
)};
```

with the fake 6th player in each team being 'false', which works for the first list item, but then every next "Team" list item has the exact same first 5 players.

Comment: this doesn't make much sense to me. Object.keys will give you an array of all keys on the object. Your code as is then loops over all of these keys. you have no logic that would prevent it from going through all keys of the object, so i'm not sure exactly what you mean by it's looping through 100 times when you only want it to go through 5 times.

Comment: You're generating an unordered list of all players on all teams and then appending that same list to each `"li.teams ul.sub_menu li"`. i doubt that's what you intended to do, but that's what the code as-written should do.

Comment: You're right, that is what is occurring. I thought Object.key would loop one key within the object at a time, do you know of the correct function I am seeking to do this? Something like a way to use Object.keys + some sort of key index?

Answer (score 0):

Move `$playerAdd += "<ul>";` and `$playerAdd += "</ul>";` to the block code of `Object.keys(team).sort().forEach(function (a) { here });`

```
Object.keys(team).sort().forEach(function (a) {
    $playerAdd += "<ul>";
    for (var i = 0; i < team[a].player.length; i++) {
        var $players = "<li><a href=\"#\">" + team[a].player[i] + "</a></li>";
        $playerAdd += $players;
    }
    $playerAdd += "</ul>";
});
```